# make and linking a library

Tags: gcc, makefile

I'm trying to compile a program which uses zeromq. There is this part of the makefile which refers to the zeromq library.

```
LIBS=-lzmq -ldl -lsqlite3 $(OPTLIBS)
```

I'm on ubuntu and the library (libzmq.so) lives in /usr/local/lib . I don't understand what lzmq refers to. Is the library registered somewhere? How can I define what path lzmq refers to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The option `-lzmq` is a linker flag, `-l`, followed by an argument, `zmq`.  The linker flag `-l` tells the linker to link the library `zmq`.  The linker will look in various directories for a library by that name, with various forms.  For example on a typical POSIX system it will look for `libzmq.so` (a shared library) followed by `libzmq.a` (a static library).

The directories it looks in are either a set of default directories (often `/usr/local/lib` is one of them, but not always), plus any directories specified on the link line with the `-L` flag.  So, adding `-L/usr/local/lib` to your link line (before the `-lzmq`) will have the linker search `/usr/local/lib` for that library.

For more details see the documentation for your compiler and linker.